# Is there a useful application of Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, meta-math

If there is, can someone provide an example of how Peano arithmetic can be used to solve a real-world problem?

If not, can someone provide an example of any axiomatic system other than ZFC that can be used to solve a real-world problem?

Comment: The rules of integer arithmetic that you learn in elementary school all hold in Peano arithmetic.  So, in that sense, anything that elementary-school arithmetic is useful for is an application of Peano arithmetic.

Comment: (1) Do you have a real-world problem solved by $\sf ZFC$? (2) Does the basis for computability and therefore the existence of computers, the internets, Al Gore, the environment, YouTube, LOLcats, and everything else that followed from that... is that enough?

Comment: I thought ZFC is the regular math that we are taught in elementary school. Am I mistaken? Is Peano arithmetic the regular math we are taught in school?

Comment: @user111887. ZFC is harldy ever taught before Master's degree, but, in some way, all math up to that level, and most afterwards, *can be based* on ZFC.

Comment: @arbautjc: I don't understand why you made that comment.

Comment: @arbautjc: No... I'm saying that computer science is in some sense an application of and application of Peano arithmetic. LOL cats are a consequence of the internet and the fact that cats rule the world, so indirectly it is an application of PA. Finally, mathematics from before 1880 was designed to have applications in the real world. Mathematics after 1880 started to be designed for its own sake, and slowly it crept away until we reached very abstract things like forcing, large cardinals, model categories and so on.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand ;-)

Comment: I agree with previous comments that is hard to stay with the idea that arithmetics and mathematics are "useless".

About axiomatization and formalization of math theories, the history of math (at least from half of XIX century) shows us that they are powerful tools for increasing our knowledge of mathematics itself.

Answer (score 4):

The setting out of the axioms of Peano Arithmetic in the 19th century was just one attempt to determine the essential properties of the natural numbers from which all other properties might be derived. In a sense, PA and other such attempts were reverse-engineered from "real-world" problems. To my knowledge, they have not resulted in any new solutions to real-world problems, but that wasn't their purpose.

Comment: You can avoid "(?)" : from Wikipedia : "In mathematical logic, the Peano axioms, also known as the Dedekind–Peano axioms or the Peano postulates, are a set of axioms for the natural numbers presented by the 19th century [...]". Richard Dedekind, *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen?* (1888) and  Richard Dedekind, "Letter to Keferstein" (1890),  and Giuseppe Peano, *Arithmetices principia, nova methodo exposita* (1889).

Answer (score 3):

When I balance my check book, I am using integer arithmetic (because I can do everything in cents).  When I get the balance from the bank at the end of each month, and compare it to my running balance I keep in my check book, I have to account for uncleared checks and things like that.  In order to do this, I end up adding and subtracting the numbers in a different order than the bank did.  That is, I use the fact that integer arithmetic is commutative and associative.  And how do I know this?  Because I can prove this using Peano's axioms.

I have to say that my faith in the Peano axioms is exceedingly great.  Because whenever the numbers in my bank balance don't work, I automatically presume that either I or the bank have made a mistake.  I never consider the possibility that I might have discovered an inconsistency in arithmetic.  And this is despite Goedel's Theorem that says I can never be sure.